# TypeError: readFile$(...).mergeMap is not a function in firebase serve functions

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-ui-router, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I followed the guide of Angular Universal: server-side rendering as explained in the official documentation of Angular:
https://angular.io/guide/universal
I managed to run the application correctly having the 2 bundles, the browser and the server bundles.
I followed the steps of the video too: Angular Universal and Firebase Hosting. And I also followed on the video: Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase using TypeScript.
I used angular-universal-express-firebase module to run the application within firebase functions and when I run the firebase serve of functions I get this error:

```
TypeError: readFile$(...).mergeMap is not a function
at ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\angular-universal-express\index.js:36:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at param (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
at param (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
at Function.process_params (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
at next (ProjectPath\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

I have this in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.3",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.1.0",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
"@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2": "^4.0.0",
"angular-universal-express-firebase": "0.0.4",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"firebase": "^5.3.0",
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.5",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.10.0",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
"sweetalert2": "^7.21.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.7.5",
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.3.0",
"ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~2.7.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
```

},
  "private": true

Can you help me?
What am I doing wrong?
Please.

Comment: `.mergeMap` is no longer a function on `Observable` from rxjs 6. You need to use `.pipe`, and import `mergeMap` from `rxjs/operators`

Answer (score 0):

`.mergeMap` is no longer a function on `Observable` from rxjs 6.

You need to use `.pipe`, and import `mergeMap` like so:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

myObservable.pipe(
    mergeMap((id) => newObservable(id)) 
)
```

Comment: But I do not have the problem with my code, the problem is inside some angular-universal-express module. I could repair the code from angular in local, but when I deploy it off in firebase the problem will happen again on the server. Maybe I should try to correct versions of modules.

Comment: Accordng to that error message, you do have an error in your code

Comment: What versions should I put in the dependencies to make it work?

Comment: If you want to use Angular 6, you will also need to use rxjs6. Why not just use the `pipe` function and the `mergeMap` operator as suggested above?

Comment: The error points to a the library angular-universal-express, which seems to not have been updated in about a year and looks to be based on Rxjs 5.4.2. Rxjs 5.5 added lettable operators which are not backwards compatible. You could try downgrading your Rxjs version to pre-5.5 or forking the library and updating it yourself.